# Facebook feed - post type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using FQL to get a users feed, the problem I am having is working out what type of post each item of the feed is.

ie

- status update
- album
- photo
- link
- video

How do I determine the type of post? The docs don't mention post type at all.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was acknowledged as a bug. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223855374358566

Answer (score 1):

You can query on a column not mentioned in the documentation -- type.  It will return a number...I think it is something like 46 = status update 56 = wall post, etc.  You'll have to figure out the rest for yourself and make some sort of parser.

Comment: Is it not deprecated? why would they leave it out of the docs?

Comment: I've concluded that Facebook doesn't care very much about complete documentation.  I haven't seen anything about type being deprecated.

Comment: This is weird. I don't think that it was the intention for developers to guess the type from the int. More so, some of the rows return an empty type. There must be a better way to find this value.

Comment: A bug for this issue: [bug link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223855374358566)